# Quick way to count number of position match of a given character between all rows pairwise

Tags: r, hamming-distance, stringdist

I have a matrix and I want to identify the number of times that each character appears in the same position between all pairwise.

A example of the way I'm doing is below, but my matrix has 10,000 rows and it's taking too long.

```
# This code will generate a dataframe with one row for each pair and columns that 
# count the number of position match each letter have  
my_letters <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
size_vector <- 175
n_vectors <- 10
indexes_vectors <- seq_len(n_vectors)

mtx <- sapply(indexes_vectors, 
              function(i) sample(my_letters, n_vectors, replace = TRUE))
rownames(mtx) <- indexes_vectors

df <- as.data.frame(t(combn(indexes_vectors, m = 2)))
colnames(df) <- c("index_1", "index_2")

for(l in my_letters){
  cat(l, "\n")
  df[,l] <- apply(df[,1:2], 1,
                  function(ids) {
                    sum(mtx[ids[1],] ==  mtx[ids[2],] & 
                          mtx[ids[1],] == l, na.rm = TRUE)
                  }) 

}
```

Comment: I might not understand exactly what is happening. Your output `df` has columns `index_1`, `index_2`, and the four letters. So in the first row, `index_1 = 1` and `index_2 = 2`. You then want to know how many times the letters appear at `mtx[2, 1]` and `mtx[1, 2]`? But then there are only two possible letters for each index pair and yet your output `df` often has more than that. You're also missing all `[x,x]` positions, though i don't know if that's intentional.

Comment: For each letter ("A", "B",  "C" and "D") I want to know how many times it appears in the _same position_ in `mtx[1, ]` and in `mtx[2, ]` not in  `mtx[2, 1]` and in `mtx[1,2]`. I'm missing `[x,x]` on purpose.

Comment: Simplified your code to use combn alone; and changed mine to use combn instead of CJ; running with different input parameters (in terms of # letters etc), those do better: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42063793#42063793

Comment: Many thanks, I made the changes and your code ran faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m1 <- t(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) 
  table(factor(mtx[df[i,1],][mtx[df[i,1],] == mtx[df[i,2],]],
               levels = my_letters))))
cbind(df, m1)
```

> ```
> >  V1 V2 A B C D
> 1   1  2 0 0 1 1
> 2   1  3 1 0 1 1
> 3   1  4 1 0 2 1
> 4   1  5 0 0 1 0
> 5   1  6 2 0 2 0
> 6   1  7 0 0 1 0
> 7   1  8 1 0 1 1
> 8   1  9 0 0 1 0
> 9   1 10 1 0 1 1
> 10  2  3 0 0 1 1
> 11  2  4 1 1 1 2
> 12  2  5 0 0 0 1
> 13  2  6 1 0 2 1
> 14  2  7 1 0 0 1
> 15  2  8 1 0 0 0
> 16  2  9 2 0 0 0
> 17  2 10 1 0 1 0
> 18  3  4 0 0 0 0
> 19  3  5 0 2 1 0
> 20  3  6 1 1 2 1
> 21  3  7 0 1 0 0
> 22  3  8 1 1 0 0
> 23  3  9 0 1 2 0
> 24  3 10 0 0 1 0
> 25  4  5 1 1 0 1
> 26  4  6 2 1 1 0
> 27  4  7 1 0 1 1
> 28  4  8 0 1 0 0
> 29  4  9 1 0 0 0
> 30  4 10 2 0 0 0
> 31  5  6 0 2 0 0
> 32  5  7 0 1 3 1
> 33  5  8 0 1 2 0
> 34  5  9 1 0 2 0
> 35  5 10 0 0 2 0
> 36  6  7 0 0 0 0
> 37  6  8 1 1 0 0
> 38  6  9 0 0 1 0
> 39  6 10 3 0 1 0
> 40  7  8 0 1 1 0
> 41  7  9 1 0 1 0
> 42  7 10 0 0 1 0
> 43  8  9 1 1 1 1
> 44  8 10 0 0 1 0
> 45  9 10 0 0 0 0
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will perform well, but it's one option:

```
library(data.table)
matchDT = setDT(melt(mtx))[, 
  CJ(row1 = Var1, row2 = Var1)[row1 < row2], by=.(value, col = Var2)]
]

dcast(matchDT, row1 + row2 ~ value)
```

This excludes row combos with no matches. To get them back, maybe...

```
levs = seq_len(nrow(mtx))
dcast(matchDT, factor(row1, levels=levs) + factor(row2, levels = levs) ~ value, drop = FALSE)[as.integer(row1) < as.integer(row2)]

Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
    row1 row2 A B C D
 1:    1    2 1 0 2 0
 2:    1    3 1 0 1 1
 3:    1    4 1 1 0 1
 4:    1    5 0 1 1 0
 5:    1    6 1 0 1 1
 6:    1    7 0 0 1 0
 7:    1    8 0 2 1 0
 8:    1    9 1 2 2 1
 9:    1   10 0 1 1 0
10:    2    3 2 0 0 0
11:    2    4 1 0 1 0
12:    2    5 0 1 1 0
13:    2    6 1 0 1 1
14:    2    7 0 0 1 0
15:    2    8 2 0 1 0
16:    2    9 1 0 1 0
17:    2   10 1 0 1 0
18:    3    4 0 0 0 2
19:    3    5 0 0 0 0
20:    3    6 1 0 0 2
21:    3    7 1 1 1 0
22:    3    8 1 0 0 1
23:    3    9 1 1 0 0
24:    3   10 1 0 1 0
25:    4    5 0 2 1 0
26:    4    6 0 1 0 2
27:    4    7 0 0 0 0
28:    4    8 1 1 0 2
29:    4    9 0 2 0 0
30:    4   10 0 2 1 0
31:    5    6 0 1 1 0
32:    5    7 0 2 1 0
33:    5    8 0 1 0 1
34:    5    9 0 1 1 0
35:    5   10 0 2 1 1
36:    6    7 0 1 2 1
37:    6    8 0 0 0 1
38:    6    9 1 1 1 0
39:    6   10 0 1 0 0
40:    7    8 0 0 1 0
41:    7    9 0 0 1 0
42:    7   10 0 1 2 0
43:    8    9 1 2 1 0
44:    8   10 1 1 1 1
45:    9   10 0 2 1 0
    row1 row2 A B C D
```

Comment: I think I've posted or seen this on SO before. Glad to delete when someone finds a dupe

Comment: Thanks, but using microbenchmark to measure the speed it seems your solution is 9 times slower than mine (14 times if I include rows with no matches), although it is undeniably more elegant.

Comment: here a link to the code I use to test: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z4kn5lc0ekg7wp3/test.R?dl=0

Comment: @celacanto Thanks, I was curious about performance. Btw, you only need one of those three dcasts to get the result. (I tested after keeping the `dcast(matchDT, factor(row1, levels=levs) + factor(row2, levels = levs) ~ value, drop = FALSE)[as.integer(row1) < as.integer(row2)]` one and the results were still 9x slower than yours, though).

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with base R:

```
l1 <- lapply(split(df, 1:nrow(df)), as.integer)

l2 <- lapply(l1, function(x) {
  m <- mtx[x[1],] == mtx[x[2],]
  l <- lapply(my_letters, '==', mtx[x[1],])
  sapply(l, function(i) sum(i & m))
})

cbind(df, setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, l2), my_letters))
```

which gives:

> ```
>    index_1 index_2 A B C D
> 1        1       2 0 0 0 0
> 2        1       3 0 0 2 1
> 3        1       4 0 0 0 1
> 4        1       5 0 1 2 0
> 5        1       6 0 0 3 1
> 6        1       7 0 1 1 3
> 7        1       8 0 1 2 2
> 8        1       9 0 0 2 1
> 9        1      10 0 0 2 0
> 10       2       3 0 1 0 1
> 11       2       4 0 1 0 2
> 12       2       5 0 1 0 0
> 13       2       6 0 0 0 2
> 14       2       7 0 1 0 1
> 15       2       8 1 0 0 0
> 16       2       9 0 1 0 2
> 17       2      10 2 1 0 3
> 18       3       4 0 0 1 0
> 19       3       5 0 0 1 1
> 20       3       6 0 0 1 1
> 21       3       7 0 1 1 2
> 22       3       8 0 0 0 1
> 23       3       9 1 0 0 0
> 24       3      10 0 0 0 1
> 25       4       5 0 2 1 0
> 26       4       6 0 0 1 1
> 27       4       7 1 1 0 1
> 28       4       8 1 1 1 1
> 29       4       9 0 1 1 2
> 30       4      10 0 1 0 2
> 31       5       6 0 1 2 0
> 32       5       7 0 1 1 0
> 33       5       8 0 2 1 0
> 34       5       9 0 1 2 0
> 35       5      10 0 2 1 0
> 36       6       7 1 0 1 1
> 37       6       8 0 0 3 1
> 38       6       9 0 1 2 0
> 39       6      10 0 0 1 1
> 40       7       8 0 1 0 2
> 41       7       9 0 1 0 1
> 42       7      10 0 0 0 1
> 43       8       9 0 0 2 1
> 44       8      10 1 1 1 0
> 45       9      10 0 0 2 1
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but using microbenchmark to measure the speed it seems your solution is slower than mine. Here is the code I use to test: https://www.dropbox.com/s/21ptsjj987c98yx/test2.R?dl=0

Comment: @celacanto benchmarking on such small datasets isn't of any use; solutions that are slow on a small dataset can fast on a large one; if you use `n_vectors <- 200` for example, Frank's solution is then faster